# No names returned when retrieving reviews via Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to retrieve all the reviews to my business page but I can only get the name of the person who's access token I'm using. Do I need an access token with an additional permission other than manage_pages?

EDIT:

Here's the URL used to get the info:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/{pageid}/ratings?access_token={accesstoken}
```

Currently it will return an item containing the rating, review text and date. But doesn't return a name for anyone but the owner of the access token. I've tried passing the open_graph_story field but it simply returns more detail about rating itself, not the name of the reviewer.

Comment: Sorry but I am having some eye problems lately :( I can't see any codes/what you tried so far in your post

Comment: There's no code to really show but I've added the URL that I call that returns the info.

Comment: are you using a page token or a user token?

Comment: Page token that was obtained using an App access token with manage_pages

Comment: then i assume the data is not available anymore for privacy reasons

Comment: In my test there is a reviewer field with name and id. I used the page access token.

Comment: @Norbert, The reviewer field is there for a review I left myself but no one else. I now believe I have to apply for more permissions and supply a privacy policy in order to access this info.